Proving Bolzano Weierstrass theorem through half line theorem

Bolzano Weierstrass theorem: Every bounded sequence has a convergent subsequence
Let $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N} }$ be a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ and let $M \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\forall n: |x_n| < M $. Consider the subset $L$ of $\mathbb{R}$ defined by $$ y \in L \iff y \leq x_n \text{ for infinitely many values of n}$$

The right side is pretty easy for me to understand when the sequence does have a limit; It is simply all the elements less than the limit, as a given number can only be less than an infinite number of numbers of the sequence if and only if that number is less than the limit. But I have a hard time decoding this infinitely many value notation for sequences which don't converge.
Could someone simplify the idea involved here more?

If $M=\infty$, then $L$ is unbounded above, which isn't much use to know.

Since the sequence is bounded, the divergence is not really of the type where it shoots of to infinity. It is rather some sort of oscillatory divergence. Think for example $(-1)^n$ @JMP

Or let $x_n={\pi^n}$, where ${}$ is the fractional part. In this case $L=(-\infty,1)$. What's the difficult bit?

I mean it's wrapping my head around this infinitely many value notation , just as I have stated in my question... @JMP but your example is nice tho

@CatharticEncephalopathy Do you know the limes superior of a sequence? If yes, then it might help trying to prove that $L\supseteq (-\infty, \limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty} x_n)$ and $L\subseteq ( -\infty, \limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty} x_n]$.
